# c#.net local database Windows Forms

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio-2012, local-database

I have a .net 4.0 Windows Forms application and a local database.
The columns are ID number, First name, Last name and Age
I also have a text box that a user types in an ID numbers and presses enter. On the enter press I want to populate a group of text boxes with the First name, Last name and age relevant to the ID number.

This is my first time using any database so I'm not really sure where to start.
I've tried google searching a few tutorials but they don't seem to focus on local databases or how to populate a text box.

If you know of any tutorials or have some code that would help, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the database is local or running on a different machine. From your code perspective you use it in exactly the same way. Just make sure that you connection string is correct (ie. it points to your local machine). Any tutorial related to querying / updating data in the database will be valid.

Comment: That proves my knowledge of Databases. Thanks, I'll just continue looking at other DB tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce) -- it doesn't cover populating text boxes specifically but should get you going on inserting and retrieving data.